# AnyLogic problem with having multiregions and regions under the roof of the same parameter type

Tags: gis, anylogic, region

I get problem with some of GIS map regions turning into multi regions as I try to use them as agents. So I applied the advised method to "create a normal agent type ("MyGISRegion") and provide it a parameter p_MyRegion of type GISRegion. For every region you create, you also now instantiate such an agent and set its parameter to the region created." and now the mentioned parameter type conflicts with regions as some of them are multi regions and some regular GISRegions. How to fix the conflict?

Comment: share some more details about what actual regions you are using. You need to decide yourself if your agents should represent GISRegions or multi-regions. Can you not simply turn the multi-regions into single regions first before turning them to agents?

Comment: Would love to unite them into one, but couldn't find the way to, here an example of these multiple ones https://i.imgur.com/UdKXdzZ.png